# Show $x^2 + y^2 + 1 = 0 \pmod m$, iff $\,m \pmod 4 \ne 0$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Show that $x^2 + y^2 + 1 = 0$ $\pmod m$ has solutions iff $\,m \pmod 4
>  \ne 0$.

I know hot to show that this equation has solutions if m = p It's easy to show "$=>$", but I'm completery stucked with the opposite direction.

Comment: what if $y = 0$ ?

Comment: for m mod 4 =0 or 2 this is simple to prove. so only odd m is interesting

Answer (score 1):

If $m\equiv0\pmod4,$ then $$x^2+y^2+1\equiv0\pmod m\implies 4\mid x^2+y^2+1$$ which is clearly impossible, so the equation has no solutions.
If $m\not\equiv0\pmod4,$ then, by multiplying by $2$ if necessary, we can reduce to the case $m\equiv2\pmod4.$ Consider the set $P=\{(mk-1\mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\}.$ If one of the elements, $p\in P$ is of the form $\prod_ip_i^{k_i}\prod_jq_j^{2l_j}$ with $p_i\equiv1\pmod 4$ and $q_j\equiv -1\pmod4,$ then by [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares),
$p$ can be written as a sum of two squares $x^2+y^2$ which shows that $m\mid x^2+y^2+1.$
If $p$ is not of that form, then without loss of generality, neglecting those $q_j$ which occur to an even exponent, we may assume it is of the form $p=\prod_ip_i^{k_i}\prod_jq_j^{2l_j+1}.$ Now consider the set $Q=\{\gamma_j:=\operatorname{ord}_mq_j\}$ (the smallest positive integer $l$ such that $q_j^l\equiv1\pmod m$). For $\gamma\in Q,$ if $\gamma$ is even, then, by [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), find $z$ such that $ \begin{cases}
z\equiv q_j\pmod{m/2}\\
z\equiv 1\pmod 4
\end{cases}.$
Then by use of [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions),
we can find a prime $q_j'$ with $q_j'\equiv z\pmod{2m}.$ Thus we have 
$$p':=p\prod\limits_{2\not\mid\gamma_j} q_j^{\gamma_j}\prod\limits_{2\mid\gamma_j}q_j^{\gamma_j-1}q_j'\equiv-1\pmod m,$$ and $p'$ is of the form $(\prod_ip_i^{k_i}\prod_{2\mid \gamma_j} q_j')\prod_{2\mid \gamma_j} q_j^{2l_j+1+\gamma_j-1}\prod_{2\not\mid\gamma_j}q_j^{2l_j+1+\gamma_j}$ where $p_i$ and $q_j'$ are $\equiv1\pmod4,$ and the exponents of the $q_j$ are even. Therefore $p'$ can be written as $x^2+y^2,$ so that $m$ divides $p'+1=x^2+y^2+1.$

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Quoting Wiki, "Since the Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity implies that the product of two integers each of which can be written as the sum of two squares is itself expressible as the sum of two squares, by applying Fermat's theorem to the prime factorization of any positive integer n, **we see that if all the prime factors of n congruent to 3 modulo 4 occur to an even exponent, then n is expressible as a sum of two squares.**" For example, $3^2\cdot5=45=6^2+3^2$ is a sum of two squares. I also edited to make some statements more precise.

Answer (score 0):

If $m \equiv 0\pmod 4$ it is simple to prove there is no solution, test all possible pairs $(x,y)$. If $2m \equiv 2\pmod 4$ then a solution can be constructed by the chinese remainder theorem from the solution of the odd $m$ and the solution $x=0,y=1$ modulo $2$. So we assume that $m$ is odd.
If $m$ is a prime then $\frac{m+1}{2}$ of the numbers $0,\ldots,m-1$ are squares. Therefore both sets $\{-x^2\mid x=0,\ldots\ m$ and $\{y^2+1\mid y=0,\ldots\ m$} contain $\frac{m+1}{2}$ elements. So the intersection of these sets is not empty. So there is a $x$ and a $y$ such that $y^2+1=-x^2$ if $m$ is an odd  prime.
Now by induction we show that the equation has a solution for every power of an odd prime.

If $(x,y)=(x_0,y_0)$ is a solution of 
$$x^2+y^2+1 \equiv 0\pmod{p^n}$$
then 
$$x_0^2+y_0^2+1=q_0p^n$$
Therefore 
$$ \begin{align}(x_0+ap^n)^2+(y_0+bp^n)^2+1&=x_0^2+y_0^2+1+2p^n(ax_0+by_0)+(a^2+b^2) p^{2n}\\&=p^n(q_0+2ax_0+2by_0)+p^{n+1}(a^2+b^2)p^{n-1}\\
&=p^n(pt)+p^{n+1}(a^2+b^2)p^{n-1}\\
&\equiv 0 \pmod {p^{n+1}}\end{align}$$
because the equation 
$$q_0+2ax_0+2by_0 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$
has a solution $(a,b) \pmod p$ and therefore 
$$q_0+2ax_0+2by_0=tp$$. 
Here is the proof:
At leas oen of $x_0$ or $y_0$ is not equal to $0$, so let's assume $x_0 \ne 0$. So we select an arbitrary b and get 
$$a=\frac{2by_0-q_0}{2x_0} \pmod{p}$$

We have shown that there is a solution if $m$ is a power of an odd prime. By the chinese remainder theorem we can construct a solution for $m$ that is a product of odd prime powers.

Comment: If you mean quadratic residue when speaking about (m+1)/2 squares, then it's a mistake, as it's only (m-1)/2 of them, so their intersection can be empty.

Comment: @sooobus: the quadratic residues modulo 5 are 0,1,4. The quadratic residues modulo 7 are 0,1,2,4. How many are this  (m-1)/2 or  (m+1)/2? I think you forgot to count 0.

Comment: I always thought the Chinese Remainder Theorem applies to **linear** congruences, how are you applying it to quadratic congruences?

Comment: If $m$ is odd, then $m$ divides $2m\equiv2\pmod4.$  So it suffices to prove the case $m\equiv2\pmod4.$ Also, may I ask why this is simple? Thanks.

Comment: @mathguy: If $a_i$ is a solution of $f(a_i)=0\pmod {m_i}$ , $f$ a polynomial and $gcd(m_imm_j)=1$,  then you can construct an $a$ such that $a=a_i\pmod{m_i}$ by the chinese remainder theorem. So we have $f(a)=f(a_i)=0 \mod{m_i}$ and so $f(a)=0 \pmod{m_1\cdots m_n}$.

Comment: @allower: I don't remember, why I thought that $m=2\pmod{4}$ is simple so I reduced it to the odd case with the chinese remainder theorem (I edited the beginning of my post)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. BTW, my pseudo-name is *awllower* not *allower*. :)